# Question about first order stochastic dominance

Tags: probability, distributions, stochastic-ordering

Suppose $x \sim F(x; s)$ where $s\in\{n, p\}$. Then let $F(x; n) \leq F(x; p) \forall x$. Can this be be a valid PDF?

It seems that other than the case where $F(x;n)=F(x;p)$ it is not possible. Letting $\int^\infty_{-\infty} F(x;p)dx = 1 $, then allowing $F(x; n) < F(x; p) \exists x$. Would this not imply: $ \int^\infty_{-\infty}  F(x; n) < \int^\infty_{-\infty}  F(x; p) = 1$ and hence contradict the possibility of $F(x;n)$ being a valid pdf?

I feel I must be misunderstanding something. So any clarification would be much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Check the definition of  first order dominance again. Carefully.